# Problem adding header line with line break in add_header_above() kableExtra

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, kableextra

I have tried to add a line break in a new header line (add_header_above), however, it produces an unexpected result that I show in the attached image, a blank box appears in the background of the new header, in addition a page is added in white before the table.

```
add_header_above(
   c("Capitales de Provincia" = 1, 
     "Población" = 3, 
     "Esfuerzo Social (€)" = 3, 
     "Población (%) \nUmbral Pobreza" = 3, 
     "Esfuerzo Social (€) \npor Habitante Pobreza" = 3,
     "Ranking Esfuerzo \nSocial por \nHabitante Pobreza" = 3
   ),
  bold = T, monospace = F, 
  line = T, line_sep = 1, escape = T,
  color="white", background="#7B7B7B"
 ) %>%
```

[image]

**UPDATE**
I update the question with the data and code in order to reproduce the problem. I hope it's enough. It is part of a fairly long rmarkdown document.

dataframe:

```
structure(
 list(
  Municipio = c("Albacete", "Alicante/Alacant", "Almería", "Ávila", "Badajoz"), 
  Población_2015 = c(172121L, 328648L, 194203L, NA, 149892L), 
  Población_2016 = c(172426L, 330525L, 194515L, 58083L, 149946L), 
  Población_2017 = c(172816L, 329988L, 195389L, 58149L, 150543L), 
  `Esfuerzo Social_2015` = c(12353570.26, 15963858.06, 14867434.39, NA, 5621106.01), 
  `Esfuerzo Social_2016` = c(10922141.66, 16781422.67, 14500734.62, 9458354.23, 5544874.22), 
  `Esfuerzo Social_2017` = c(11450013.65, 18298031.66, 13157434.34, 9271539.84, 6009806.4), 
  `Umbral Pobreza_2015` = c(22.7, 30.1, 31.1, NA, 25.2), 
  `Umbral Pobreza_2016` = c(21.3, 29.3, 30.3, 20.4, 24.7), 
  `Umbral Pobreza_2017` = c(21, 28.8, 30.3, 19.2, 24.4), 
  `Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2015` = c(316.178818164161, 161.376528349591, 246.161260502216, NA, 148.813654031961), 
  `Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2016` = c(297.389375010653, 173.283352552421, 246.033519096197, 798.245295862952, 149.713119935052),
  `Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2017` = c(315.502468080557, 192.536795740384, 222.243195418222, 830.440248327572, 163.610092122255),
  `Ranking Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2015` = c(28, 46, 38, NA, 47), 
  `Ranking Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2016` = c(36, 47, 40, 4, 48), 
  `Ranking Esfuerzo Social por Habitante Pobreza_2017` = c(37, 46, 43, 4, 48)), 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code:

```
dfapo %>%
 kable(
  caption="Título", 
  row.names = F,
  col.names = c(
   "Municipio", 
   "2015", "2016", "2017", 
   "2015", "2016", "2017", 
   "2015", "2016", "2017",
   "2015", "2016", "2017", 
   "2015", "2016", "2017"
  ),
  digits = 2, 
  centering = FALSE,
  format.args = list(big.mark = ".", decimal.mark = ","),
  booktabs = F, 
  vline = "", 
  linesep = "",
 ) %>%
 kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("hover", "condensed", "responsive"), 
  html_font="\"Trebuchet MS\", verdana, sans-serif", 
  latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down", "HOLD_position"),
  full_width = F, fixed_thead = T) %>%
  landscape() %>%
 add_header_above(
  c("Capitales de Provincia" = 1, 
     "Población" = 3, 
     "Esfuerzo Social (€)" = 3, 
     "Población (%) \nUmbral Pobreza" = 3, 
     "Esfuerzo Social (€) \npor Habitante Pobreza" = 3,
     "Ranking Esfuerzo \nSocial por \nHabitante Pobreza" = 3
   ),
  color="white", background="#7B7B7B", 
  bold = T, monospace = F
 )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please provide the whole code to reproduce your table?

Comment: Thanks for answering @bttomio. I update the question with the data and code.

Comment: Did you try `escape = F`?

Comment: Check more information here: http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/best_practice_for_newline_in_latex_table.pdf

Comment: With escape = F in add_header_above the line break is not produced in the PDF output

Comment: Only with escape set to TRUE does the line break in add_header_above occur, but in that case, two problems occur, a blank page is added before the table, and a white square appears in the elements of the added header. Just as I have described the problem.

Comment: I cannot replicate your image. Nevertheless, the white space appears too. I would say it is a bug. You could search for help on https://github.com/haozhu233/kableExtra/issues